# Cron Permission denied

Tags: server, permissions, sudo, cron

I'm running a python script called TGubuntu.py.
I used `ls -l` , and the permissions of the script are `-rwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu   503 Jan 13 19:07 TGubuntu.py`, which should mean that anyone can execute the file, right?

But I still get the error in the log:

```
From: root@ip-censoredfroprivacy.compute.internal (Cron Daemon)
To: ubuntu@ip-censoredforprivacy.compute.internal
Subject: Cron <ubuntu@ip-censoredforprivacy> /home/ubuntu/TestTG/TGubuntu.py
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/ubuntu>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=ubuntu>
Message-Id: <20200114033701.21E4F46511@ip-censoredforprivacy.us-east-2.compute.internal>
Date: Tue, 14 Jan 2020 03:37:01 +0000 (UTC)
/bin/sh: 1: /home/ubuntu/TestTG/TGubuntu.py: Permission denied
```

When I run the script manually it works perfectly.
Any Ideas?

Comment: My guess is that the Python script pulls in another file (by reading, writing, importing etc.) that the executing user of the script is not allowed to read/write/import.

Comment: @Jos I do import some python modules, is that the problem? How can I make cron execute with the highest perms so that nothing can stop it?

Comment: How did you write your Cron entry? Is your home directory encrypted? Did you try to move that script to another directory, like `/usr/local/bin` and run from there?

Comment: Importing installed modules should not be a problem. Try to debug your Python script by writing entries to a log file somewhere, so you can see on which line contains the error. If you let your script be executed by entering it in `sudo crontab -e` it will run with root permissions.

Comment: @Jos even with root permissions it says permission denied.and btw,  Cron is outputting the log to var/mail/root